# How to flush performance_schema stats without restarting MySQL?

Tags: mysql, performance

I know stats in performance schema are not persistent over MySQL restarts. 
I want to flush all stats without restarting MySQL. Is there any way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Which metrics do you find interesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TRUNCATE TABLE` can be used to reset statistics.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-table-characteristics.html

> Summary tables can be truncated with TRUNCATE TABLE. Generally, the
>   effect is to reset the summary columns to 0 or NULL, not to remove
>   rows. This enables you to clear collected values and restart
>   aggregation.

Answer (score 13):

Easier then truncating each separate table would be to call the procedure:

```
CALL sys.ps_truncate_all_tables(FALSE);
```

[MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sys-ps-truncate-all-tables.html)