# How to "reset" mariadb GLOBAL STATS?

Tags: mariadb

I trying to tune up my Mariadb server and to see if my new config is better I want to use `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`. command, but find out a problem.

I can't reset status of query `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;`.

1. Tried use `FLUSH STATUS;`, query done without error, but no result.
2. Tried UPDATE the table in information_schema, but I have no permission using even root user.
3. Tried to use SESSION status, but have same problem.

Is only way to get STATUS of new confg is to save current ones and distract them from new ones I will get in future?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42758188/how-to-flush-performance-schema-stats-without-restarting-mysql)

Comment: But global status is in information_schema, not performance_schema

Comment: I will try to make use of this

Answer (score 2):

`FLUSH STATUS` resets *some* settings for the session.  I find it convenient for `Handler%` values when trying to figure out how a query is working.

InnoDB settings are necessarily "global".  That is, there are no "session" counterpart, yet `SHOW SESSION STATUS` shows the global ones.

Restarting MariaDB/MySQL will reset all the `STATUS`.

To get 'diffs', you should do `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` (or session), before and after, then manually calculate the diffs.

Note that fetching the stats via `SELECT ... FROM information_schema...` is like the Heisenberg principle -- the act of selecting modifies the values (or at least some of them).  Hence, my recommendation for doing `SHOW`.  Note: The `SHOW` generates output that is just like a `SELECT` of a 2-column table with a few hundred rows.

The `information_schema` is not really a regular database; it is just a view of some in-memory variables.  It is not writable.